# Calculate average over column after group separation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I've got `DataFrame` with columns `a` and `b`, where `b` contains the values `Y` or `N` corresponding for `True` and `False`.

I'd like to group by `a` and then, for each group, get the average of `b's (meaning, the number of`True`s in the group divided by the number of lines in that group).

What I've got so far is

```
data['b'] = data['b'].map({'Y': True, 'N': False})
data.groupby('a', as_index=False)['b'].mean()
```

But I guess that's not the direction..

---

Example of data:

```
a   b
1   Y
1   Y
1   N
2   Y
2   Y
2   N
2   N
```

And the output should be

```
a   avg
1   2/3
2   1/2
```

Comment: What do you mean by average of Y's per value of a? Can you show us some data and expected output?

Comment: I added a better explanation and an example.

Comment: Btw, your code appears to output the same thing, so what is wrong with it?

Comment: Your answer works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.a,df.b,normalize='index').Y
Out[336]: 
a
1    0.666667
2    0.500000
Name: Y, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd do this with `groupby` and `value_counts(normalize=True)`:

```
df.groupby('a')['b'].value_counts(normalize=True).unstack(1)['Y']

a
1    0.666667
2    0.500000
Name: Y, dtype: float64
```

No conversion/replacement/map needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way also:

```
df.assign(avg=df.b=='Y').groupby('a')['avg'].mean()
```

Output:

```
a
1    0.666667
2    0.500000
Name: avg, dtype: float64
```

Add `reset_index`:

```
   a       avg
0  1  0.666667
1  2  0.500000
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `numpy.bincount`

```
i, a = data['a'].factorize()
b = (data['b'].values == 'Y')

pd.DataFrame(dict(a=a, avg=np.bincount(i, b) / np.bincount(i)))

   a       avg
0  1  0.666667
1  2  0.500000
```